# Не работает модуль в 1с форме

Tags: 1с, формы

Теперь подумаем над тем, как автоматически заполнить поле Наименование на
основе данных полей Физическое лицо и Подразделение. Сделать это можно различными
способами, мы реализуем следующую функциональность: перехватим события изменения
полей Физическое лицо и Подразделение и вызовем в обработчике каждого из этих
событий процедуру, заполняющую поле Наименование. Так пользователь, заполняющий
элемент справочника, сможет сразу же увидеть результаты формирования наименования.
Нашей задаче отвечает следующий код:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ФизическоеЛицоПриИзменении(Элемент)
 СформироватьНаименование();
КонецПроцедуры
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПодразделениеПриИзменении(Элемент)
 СформироватьНаименование();
КонецПроцедуры
Процедура СформироватьНаименование()
 Объект.Наименование=Объект.ФизическоеЛицо.Наименование +" ("+
 Объект.Подразделение.Наименование+") ";
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вписываю все корректно, но в форме автозаполнение не работает! прошу помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вы просто скопировали код в модуль формы. Этого не достаточно. Нужно связать процедуры-обработчики с элементами формы.

Позиционируетесь на нужном элементе, жмете ПКМ -> Свойства (или сочетание "Ctrl+E")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вкладка "События", событие "ПриИзменении", нажимаете стрелку вниз и выбираете, какое событие привязать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо, можно нажать кнопку с изображением лупы, тогда откроется конструктор для создания события. И после можно будет в созданный метод скопировать нужный код.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что для полей ввода формы прописан обработчик `ПриИзменении`, иногда бывает глюк формы, и необходимо перейти в процедуру через кнопку "Открыть"

Второй вариант, ставьте точки остановки и в режиме отладки проверяйте, срабатывает перехват или нет.